Why is my cube disappearing when I add a difference boolean with a mesh created from text?
I've been following this tutorial. While it is old, I'm working on the assumption that boolean operations are a pretty fundemental feature and won't have changed much. I'm using Blender 4.1.
I have a text object (it's an odd font) which I've extruded and converted to a mesh. I also have a cube which I've scaled to be about the same size.
The two objects have been positioned so they intersect.

When I add a Difference Boolean, the cube vanishes entirely. The text is left intact (including the portion that was intersecting with the cube).
Download the file

My goal was to cut the text out of the cube. What have I done wrong?


you can try fast solver instead of exact

I tried that in this version which is an improvement, but it only seems to partially cut the cube. Some of the text isn't engraved properly. It's clearer to see in an STL export


boolean modifier needs manifold meshes, with right face orientation, that's the most common mistake

I don't know how to go about determining if that is the problem or how to resolve it if it is.

That's a very old tutorial from 7 years ago using Blender 2.7! What version of Blender are you using? (We can't see from your images because they're too small.) Use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu to create your image then edit your question and add them into your question. A Blend file would be helpful too whcih you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

boolean modifier needs manifold meshes, with right face orientation, that's the most common mistake. Also you can try fast solver instead of exact. If that doesn't help, pls provide blend file as John said.

@JohnEason - Thanks. I've updated the question. I couldn't use blend-exchange since the file is too big (I suspect its embedding the font I used) but I think I've covered everything else you recommended.

@Chris - Thanks for the advice. I've updated the question.

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
The "Text" object is not a manifold:

To check that, use the menu entry Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold.
Consequently, the Self Intersection option is required by the Boolean modifier:

But interior faces are remaining... The culprit seems "Bevel" in obtuse angles.

To debug, you can restrict tests to the pathologic Omega character, saving a lot of time...
